# Redirect from ruby on rails to angular giving Response for preflight is invalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cors

I have an app with front-end in angular 4 and back-end in rails 5.

I have integrated a payment service in my app which posts success response back to the given url. Since the response is in post format so I cannot handle it on angular.So I have given back-end's url as the redirect url.

Now I want to redirect to front-end(angular) providing response of the payment service.

On using rails redirect_to method it is giving me an error:

> Response for preflight is invalid

but sometimes the error is

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See the following documentation and follow how you can avoid pre-flight requests. If pre-flight request is a must then it need to be fixed in the server with the right methods, origins and headers.

When a preflight request will be sent is clearly documented under the following documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

```
In particular, a request is preflighted if any of the following conditions is true:

If the request uses any of the following methods:
PUT
DELETE
CONNECT
OPTIONS
TRACE
PATCH
Or if, apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, or any of the other header with a name defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”), the request includes any headers other than those which the Fetch spec defines as being a “CORS-safelisted request-header”, which are the following:
Accept
Accept-Language
Content-Language
Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below)
Last-Event-ID
DPR
Downlink
Save-Data
Viewport-Width
Width
Or if the Content-Type header has a value other than the following:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
Or if one or more event listeners are registered on an XMLHttpRequestUpload object used in the request.
Or if a ReadableStream object is used in the request.
```